# Subtotals in a column based on ranges in another column

Tags: excel

Consider a table like the following:

```
WEEKNUM    HOURS     WEEKTOTAL
==============================
   1         2         
   1         4           6
   2         3      
   2         5     
   2         1           9
   3         6           6
  ...       ...         ...
```

I am searching for a formula to use in the WEEKTOTAL column that sums those entries in the HOURS column that share the same weeknumber. I would like the actual subtotal entry to be added in the row that contains the last occurrence of each weeknumber (the entries are likely sorted by weeknumber). The other cells in this column can be empty.

I'm hoping this is possible using an `ARRAYFORMULA`, but I am not sure how to.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: explore SUMIFS() and pls share if it works/not..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "WEEKTOTAL" cell is C1.

in C2 :

```
=IF(A2<>A3,SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,-1*COUNTIF(A:A,A2))),"")
```

and drag downwards.

Idea : use countif() to 'drive' offset() range. Which in turn will be the range for sum(). All only happens if the next column a value is different (`IF(A2<>A3, .. )` ).

Pls share if it works/not/understandable.

Comment: Hi @p._phidot_, Thanks for your answer. I played around with it myself for a while and ended up with the same idea of using not equals to check for a new week. I came up with:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A$2:A$1000<>A$3:A$1001, SUMIF(A$2:A$1000, A$2:A$1000, B$2:B$1000), IFERROR(1/0)))` in cell C2, and seems to work like a charm.